# arm-none-eabi-gdb python fatal error (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-22.04, arm-none-eabi-gcc

in my Ubuntu 22.04, I wanted to open a GDB client to connect to openocd. So I used arm-none-eabi-gdb, however I received the following error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bld-tools/bld-tools-virtual-env/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f1c996e7c00 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Previously the PYTHONPATH was set to a ros humble directory but I've removed ros humble completely (just now), that's why it became not set.

For the PYTHOMHOME, it wasn't set from the start.

I've also tried reinstalling my python. I installed python 3.11.4 (previous version was 3.10.2)

To what path should I set the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH into? Moreover is there anything more that I should configure?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Python 3.10, but arm-none-eabi-gdb needs Python 3.8.

Changing to **gdb-multiarch** was the solution for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, for me arm-none-eabi-gdb v.12.1 works, but v.13.2 doesn't. Python3 version is 3.10, so arm-none-eabi-gdb works with python 3.10.

Comment: Ok, that's weird. As I mentioned gdb v12 worked with only python 3.10 but gdb v13 didn't. When I installed python3.8, v13 started working correctly. Now I wonder why v12 was working the whole time...